# geo uri with icon\label on google maps

Tags: cordova, geo, google-maps-mobile

I'm refering to google maps mobile app trough geo uri in my phonegap applications like that:

`mapString = "geo:"+data.lat + "," + data.lng+"?saddr=("+data.lat+ "," + data.lng+")&daddr=&z=18";`

the map is open ok with zoom and in the right place, but I also want to add google apps label \ icon on the point.

how can I do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
geo:?q=lat,lon (label)
```

No idea about the icon though.